# Does anyone know how to have a score increasing via a label

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

Baically i have created a simple maths game and made it display whether the question is right or wrong, but i can't get the score to update, also does anyone know how I can get the questions to refresh onto another question, I tried app.update ?:

```
            self.a1button = Tkinter.Button(self, background="blue",foreground="white", text = (random_row.A1), command = self.QUESTION1)
            self.a1button.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = 'W')

            self.label5 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "Score:")
            self.label5.grid(row = 14, column = 1, columnspan = 5, sticky = 'S')

            self.label7 = Tkinter.Label(self, text = 0 )
            self.label7.grid(row = 14, column = 6, columnspan = 1, sticky = 'E')

def QUESTION1(self):

    if self.a1button['text'] == self.label6['text']:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("CORRECT", "WELL DONE")
        label7 = +100
        app.refresh
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("INCORRECT", "YOU FULLY GOT IT WRONG :/")
        label7 = -100
        app.refresh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first *read* the current score from the label, add or subtract the 100 point, then *set* the label again:

```
score = int(self.label7.get())
score += 100
self.label7.set(str(score))
app.refresh()
```

Note that you need to *call* the `refresh` method as well, not just reference it.

Use -= to subtract.